Trace of symmetric part of product of 3 positive semidefinite matrices
Suppose we have 3 symmetric positive semi-definite matrices $A,B,C$. How can one prove or give counter-example for the following statement?
$$ 
\mathrm{trace}(AB(A-C)^2 + (A-C)^2BA) \ge 0
$$
where we recall that $(A-C)^2 = (A-C)^{\top}(A-C)$ is positive semi-definite since the matrices $A,C$ are symmetric.

This is not true in general. First of all note
$$\text{tr}\Big(AB(A-C)^2+(A-C)^2BA\Big)=2\cdot\text{tr}\Big(AB(A-C)^2\Big)$$
A sufficient counterexample is
$$A=\begin{pmatrix}1&0\\0&0\end{pmatrix},\;\;B=\begin{pmatrix}1&1\\1&1\end{pmatrix},\;\;C=\begin{pmatrix}1&-1\\-1&2\end{pmatrix}$$
and the product is
$$AB(A-C)^2=\begin{pmatrix}-1&3\\0&0\end{pmatrix}$$
While the trace of the product of two symmetric PSD matrices is nonnegative, that is not generally true for three PSD matrices.

Edit 1: realised my first set of counterexamples had an arithmetic error, have found a set that does work now

Edit 2: was asked about the motivation for coming up with these counterexamples. Here was my thinking.
Essentially we want to trial setting as many elements as we can to 0 or 1. As $A$ appears twice, in order to reduce arithmetic, let's try the very simple$$A=\begin{pmatrix}1&0\\0&0\end{pmatrix}$$Then for $B$ let's try the simple yet slightly-less constraining: $$B=\begin{pmatrix}1&1\\1&1\end{pmatrix}$$Then for $C$ let's try setting the top-left element to be $1$ so $(A-C)$ has a 0 in that spot, ie $$C=\begin{pmatrix}1&x\\x&y\end{pmatrix}$$
So we have$$\therefore AB(A-C)^2=\begin{pmatrix}x(x+y)&x^2+xy+y^2\\0&0\end{pmatrix}$$Setting $x=-1$ and $y>1$ will give us our negative trace. We can also show that any $y\geq1$ when $x=-1$ will result in $C$ being PSD, so let's just choose $y=2$ to complete the counterexample.

Could you provide some motivation how you came up with the counter example?

Thank you for the answer!

Apologies I realised there was a mistake in the arithmetic of the first answer and motivation I provided (matrix multiplications amirite). I've edited the main answer to provide some motivation.
